# python novice sorted function and extend method of list

Tags: python, list

```
n1=['a','b','c']

n2=[1,2,3]  

n3=sorted(n1)+sorted(n2)  

n4=sorted(n1).extend(sorted(n2))
```

The problem is `n3` is working fine but `n4` is not. Why can't extend be after `sorted()`?

Answer (score 1):

Though `sorted()` returns a sorted list, the problem is that `extend()` mutates the list and returns `None`, so you can achieve what you want by:

```
n4 = sorted(n1)
n4.extend(sorted(n2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using extend correctly 
the command

```
n1.extend (n2)
```

returns a list called n1 which is ['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 1 , 2 , 3 ].

This is because you are extending a list.

Answer (score 0):

`extend` returns None.

```
print 'n2.extend([4]): ', n2.extend([4])
>>>> n2.extend([4]):  None
print 'n2', n2
>>>> n2 [1, 2, 3, 4]
```